# Why does my fetch request return the whole webpage (and not the json)?

Tags: javascript, json, server, fetch

I have a GET request on my server retrieving some JSON data from a third party site.

I now want to get that JSON data from my server by making a request from my front end to my server, this is the part that I am having trouble with.

Here is how it works in my head:

Step 1: my server makes a `GET` request to a third party site and is returned JSON

Step 2: my frontend makes a request to my server in order to retrieve that JSON data

My front end fetch request:

```
async function getData() {  
    let reqConfig = {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        })
    }

    fetch('***relative-url-pointing-to-my-server***', reqConfig)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
}
getData();
```

However, when I view the console logs I receive this following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

If I then change the `response.json()` to `response.text()`, it then returns the `HTML` of the whole page, but I want to return just the JSON that the serverside request has retrieved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your url is suppose to returns a JSON object ?

Comment: you may be getting an error response that is in html

Comment: @Nicolas - My URL is the url of the page that houses the api request to the third party site. What I am trying to do is make it so that I can essentially get the json from the third party site but I guess i am 'piping' through my server before it gets to the front end.
In answer to your question, no I am not sure that my server should return a json obj, but i am sure that the third party site does

Comment: @jidexl21 - No error message, it's simply returning the whole page

Comment: @Nicolas yeah what you're attempting wouldn't work that way. You cannot pipe a json through a webpage like that.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali - So what way would you recommend if I wanted to make a serverside request to get json from a third party > use a get request to to get that same json from my server?

Comment: @Jonny you could have your server backend make a call to the third party api and then pass it along as a json response on an endpoint on your server.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali thanks for your suggestion. This is what I am getting at I think, I just don't know the process to go about doing that. Sorry for another question but what do you mean exactly when you say 'pass it along as a json response on an endpoint on your server? Thanks once again - I am not too familiar with transferring data in this way

Comment: @Jonny Maybe you should read this first and get more familiar as to why JSON is used in modern web api methods --> https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali Thank you for that link, potentially helpful. It's a more complicated process than I originally thought. I thought I would be able to get the data on to my server, and simply request it from there from the front end. Thanks once again for your input

Comment: Try adding dataType: "json" in reqConfig .It may help.